# logging.required issue in appscan?

Tags: logging

I ran an appScan for my workspace and found many definitive errors.
However, I have not resolved this loggin.required issue:

```
try {
    proxy.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    log.debug("Calling service wipeoutChallengeAndResponse method...");
    WipeoutChallengeAndResponseOutput output= proxy.wipeoutChallengeAndResponse(input);
    if(output!=null && output.getResponse()!=null) {
        Response response= output.getResponse();
        responseBean.setStatusCode(response.getResponseCode()+"");
        responseBean.setStatusDescription(response.getResponseDescription());           
    }
    log.debug("Exit");
    return true;
} catch (UserNotExistFault e1) {
    log.debug("Exception caught in UserNotExistFault Message: ");
    //logging.Required
    String[] str = {e1.getMessage(), e1.getFaultString()};
    String errormsg = UserManagementUtil.processFaultMsg(str);
    responseBean.setErrorMessage(errormsg);
```

Comment: the error is in the line String[] str = {e1.getMessage(), e1.getFaultString()};

Comment: Please *[edit] the question* to state the exact error message (including line number that matches the line number in the code as pasted in the question, you probably also want to restate an exact copy of that line so we know for sure which one it is).  This information needs to be *in the question*, not just a comment. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the scanner is saying when you capture an error/exception message, you should log it.  The scanner is looking for something like log.err type call with str in it.

Comment: Anybody know if there's a way to tell AppScan that a particular function is a logging function? I've got a lot of Logging.Required errors because it doesn't recognize my logging function.